# ASP.NET MVC textarea tag helper for ntext property is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, tag-helpers

I've a following model propertyies one of which is projectDescription that generates an `ntext` column in SQL Server.

**Model**:

```
--some other properties here....

[Display(Name = "Project Title")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(125)")]
        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public string ProjectDesctiption { get; set; }

--some other properties here....
```

This property is bound to a `textarea` tag in a `View` as follows. But instead of displaying the real data from the `ProjectDesctiption` column from the Db it oddly displays the entire html source page of the View the page - as shown in image below. Other tags correctly display the data as shown in ProjectTitle field in the same image below. I think the issue is related to ntext datatype and the [ASP Tag helper for textarea](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc-6-textarea-tag-helper.aspx). I did check in the database that the max length of some data cell in the ProjectDescription is quite big - about 61968 characters. But we do want to display the data from this column with a reasonable textarea length and width with horizontal and vertical scrollbars so user can at least glance through the data of this field to get an idea of what the project description is (for example) or may be copy/past the data from the textrea for some purpose. **Question**: How can I achieve this goal?

**View**:

```
---some html here.....
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProjectTitle" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ProjectTitle" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProjectTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProjectDesctiption" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea asp-for="ProjectDesctiption" class="form-control" rows="6" cols="15" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProjectDesctiption" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
...some other html here...
```

[image]

Comment: Side note - from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187993.aspx) _IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types_

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good point. I should change it to nvarchar(max) or better yet - varchar(max) unless there is a compelling reason to use nvarchar. The Db in question is actually a conversion from an Ms Access Db and I'm assuming whomever converted it probably used a Microsoft's Migration tool that automatically converted Access's text columns to ntext in SQL Server. But I'll check, in our case, whether nvarchar is needed or varchar(max) will be suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `<textarea>` is not a self closing tag and because you have not 'closed' it, its displaying the html that follows the tag.

Change you code to

```
<textarea asp-for="ProjectDesctiption" class="form-control" rows="6" cols="15"></textarea>
```

Comment: You might also want to consider renaming it to `ProjectDescription` :)

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you for this and catching spelling error).